# Attaching SQL database behaviors

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to create a setup.exe that installs an application I've written.

The application uses a database to store and retrieve information.

In the setup, I have the installing user supply a Database server\instance, credentials and the DATA directory to copy the database files to.

I want to programmatically and permanently attach the database.

I use the following to programmatically attach a database to my instance.
The con.Open() and con.Close() are just for testing.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

ServerConnection serverconn = new ServerConnection(con);        
Server s = new Server(serverconn);
s.DetachDatabase("DBX2", true, true);
s.AttachDatabase("DBX2", new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection { @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DBX2.mdf", @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DBX2_log.ldf" }, AttachOptions.None);

con.Open();
MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened");
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Connection Closed");
```

Several questions to just confirm:

1. I get an error that it is already open, when it tries con.Open(), so does attaching a database this way automatically open it? When I remove the con.open(), it runs through and closes it just fine.
2. When I attach my database this way, I do not see it attached in the SQL Server Management Studio, like if I were to manually attach it there. So is the database still attached and working after I exit my application, so that other applications can access it? Is attaching this way temporary, or is it just not picked up by the SQL Management Studio?
3. Is this the correct way to go about achieving what I want?

Comment: Connecting to a database in YOUR application will not create a connection in another application (SSMS).  Also, what if the user doesn't have SSMS?  Should they be able to run your application without having to install a multi-megabyte SQL IDE ?

Comment: @Neil, my application just initializes client side executables that will need to be accessing the database, even after my application closes.

Comment: Sure, but do these client side executables also /require/ SSMS, or do they 'use a database' ?  Bear in mind, you do not need SSMS for your c# application to run, it just needs a connection string that points to a SQL Server (which could be SQL Express or one of the myriad other SQL servers).

Comment: @Neil, clients just need to access the database. they don't need SSMS. I'm just concerned that I don't see it in SSMS, because I thought that it would need to be seen there in order for my Sequel Server to allow the clients to see and access it. Because I thought that SMSS shows all attached databases.

Comment: Each application has it's own independent 'connection string' that provides a way to connect to the same database.  SSMS and other client executables are just more of these applications.   Of course, each connection string could actually be the same thing as they all point to the same database, they are just stored differently.

Comment: Thanks Neil, you were very helpful. I was under the impression that SSMS was integrated with Sequel Server and would automatically read all attached databases. If you post it as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each application has it's own independent 'connection string' that provides a way to connect to the same database. SSMS and other client executables are just more of these applications. Of course, each connection string could actually be the same thing as they all point to the same database, they are just stored differently.